# how to restrict the deletion of account if they have contact in lookup without coding

Tags: lookup, account, contact

if account and contact in lookup ralationship and if i dont want to delete the Account, and i want to restrict the deletion of account, so how can you do that.Without coding and without cheked Box.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Can you add more details to you question? What have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck? Please visit [help] & [ask] to know more about the guidelines for this site.

Comment: I want to restrict the User from deletion form Account object record if they have lookup with contact object record how we can do this without coding

Comment: I must ask; is the exclusion of code use because you don't have the skills or simply because this is an interview question?

Comment: When someone asks you for clarification, repeating the words you've already said is not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This would normally be done using an appropriate apex trigger, but since you want to avoid code this **can** be done using a before deletion record triggered flow, though the error the user will see is not at all helpful (and the admins will receive flow application error emails).

The flow-based approach is:

1. Create a new "Record-Triggered Flow" on `Account`, triggered when "A record is deleted". No entry conditions required.
2. Add a `Get Records` flow element, "Find related Contacts", that:

   1. Gets records of object `Contact`.
   2. Filters to find those where `AccountId` equals `$Record > Id`.
   3. Only stores the first record ("How many records to store") and then only the `Id` field ("Choose fields and let Salesforce do the rest").
3. Add a `Decision` with:

   1. Outcome "None found".
   2. ("All Conditions Are Met") with just one condition "Contact from Find_related_Contacts" operator "Is Null", value `$GlobalConstant.True`.
   3. Set the "Default Outcome" label to "Found at least one".
4. Add a `Delete Records` element in the "Found at least one" branch:

   1. Label it "Prevent the Account being deleted".
   2. "Use the IDs stored in a record variable or record collection variable".
   3. Select Record(s) to Delete using `$Record` itself.
5. Save the flow with a name like "Prevent deletion when at least one Contact exists".
6. Activate the flow.

This flow will look something like:

[image: The record deletion flow that prevents deletion when Contacts exist]

It seems perverse to use the `Delete Records` element, set to delete the same `Account`, to actually prevent the deletion of that `Account`. However, this works by generating an error and this prevents the original deletion. The error happens because you can't delete a given record from within the trigger when that trigger is handling the deletion of that very same record.

Deleting an `Account` with no related `Contact` records will work, but the user will see an error similar to the following if related `Contact` records do exist:

[image: The error when trying to delete an Account with Contacts]

By naming the flow differently, e.g. "Account has at least one Contact" would make the error perhaps work better for users, since they will see something like:

> We can't save this record because the “Account has at least one Contact” process failed.

Like I said, the best way to handle this correctly would be to use an Apex trigger where you can control exactly what the error message should be.

Comment: I have a small piece of invocable apex that just throws an exception of type myCustomFlowException, it takes a String parameter for the error message.
Whenever I need a flow to raise an exception, I add this as an element. It works well in this prevent delete use case. The error message in the UI is still ugly though

Comment: @RobD, yes that's a good alternative if you have someone able to write code for you (yes, it's not much code, but it is still code and will need unit tests etc.). I was demonstrating a means to do this without any code, just using standard Salesforce stuff, as requested by the OP.